# Google pubsub_v1 subscriber pull "too many files open"

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, grpc-python

There seems to be an issue in 
google-cloud-pubsub==0.39.1
google-api-python-client==1.7.8

In which doing a pull in a loop when the credentials goes bad causes a flood of `python3 1456 root   71u     IPv4              46501      0t0      TCP XXX-XXXXX-XXXX:47074->YYYYYYYY-YY-YYYYY.1e100.net:https (CLOSE_WAIT)`files to remain open and eventually cause a "too many files open" issue.

The problem does not appear to be in pubsub itself but in gRPC.

> May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:   File "/opt///lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:     return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:   File "/opt///lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 562, in **call**
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:     return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:   File "/opt///lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 466, in _end_unary_response_blocking
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:     raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]: grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]: #011status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]: #011details = "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', '{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."\n}')"
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]: #011debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1557354881.258250528","description":"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', '{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."\n}')","file":"src/core/lib/security/credentials/plugin/plugin_credentials.cc","file_line":79,"grpc_status":14}"
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]: >
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:   File "/opt///lib/python3.6/site-packages/lt/cloud/cloudpull.py", line 113, in subscribeToStuff
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:     pull_response = subscriber.pull(subscription_path, max_messages=NUM_MESSAGES, timeout=60, retry=None)
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:   File "/opt///lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/_gapic.py", line 45, in 
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:     fx = lambda self, *a, **kw: wrapped_fx(self.api, *a, **kw)  # noqa
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:   File "/opt///lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/gapic/subscriber_client.py", line 860, in pull
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:     request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:   File "/opt///lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in **call**
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:     return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:   File "/opt///lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 102, in func_with_timeout
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:   File "/opt///lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:     six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]:   File "", line 3, in raise_from
>   May  8 22:34:41  .sh[17736]: google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', '{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."\n}')

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5523

Notice at the bottom `client.api.transport._channel.close()`

A `pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient` falls into the client category.

So you can do like...

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient(credentials=credentials)
try:
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project, subscription)
    pull_response = subscriber.pull(subscription_path, max_messages=NUM_MESSAGES, timeout=60, retry=None)
    for msg in pull_response.received_messages:
        #do stuff
finally:
    subscriber.api.transport._channel.close()
```

You can do this in a loop and keep your process from opening too many files :)